# Subsuming the Linux packet processing stack

Tags: python, linux, networking

We occasionally have to debug glitchy Cisco routers that don't handle the TCP Selective Acknowledgment (SACK) options correctly. This causes our TCP sessions to die when routed through an IPTABLES port redirection rule.

To help with the diagnosis, I've been constructing a python-based utility to construct a sequence of packets that can reproduce this error at will, the implementation uses raw sockets to perform this trick. I've got an ICMP ping working nicely but I've run into a snag on the UDP implementation, I can construct, send and receive the packet without problem, the issue that I'm seeing is that Linux doesn't like the UDP packets being sent back from the remote system and always sends an ICMP Destination unreachable packet, even though my python script is able to receive and process the packet without any apparent problems.

My question: Is it possible to subsume the Linux UDP stack to bypass these ICMP error messages when working with RAW sockets?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you receiving and processing the packet and only need to suppress the ICMP port-unreachable? If so, maybe just add an entry to the iptables OUTPUT chain to drop it?

Comment: Interesting suggestion, it would certainly work, I reckon, I'd prefer a less drastic solution if possible.

Comment: It appears that IPTABLES may be the only way to go, RAW sockets are for sending only, AF_PACKET sockets can be used to capture return packets but can't prevent the Linux network stack from processing them.